# What is the difference between Sheets.Select and Sheets.Activate?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

In VBA for Excel, what is the difference between **`Sheets.Select`** and **`Sheets.Activate`** ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x62t5306%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: You might also want to see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference is in their flexibility.

`Activate` make the specified sheet the active sheet, and may only be applied to a single sheet

`Select` allow for optionally *extending* the currently selected sheets to include the specified sheet, eg

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select Replace:=False
```

and also allow for selecting an array of sheets

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet3", "Sheet2")).Select
```

---

In their minimal form `Select` and `Activate` do the same thing.

For example, if only one sheet is currently selected (say `Sheet3`) or if more than one sheet is selected but *excluding* say `Sheet2`, then `Worksheets("Sheet2").Select` and `Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate` both make `Sheet2` the sole selected and active sheet.

On the other hand, if say both `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` are selected and `Sheet2` is the active sheet, then `Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate` leaves both sheets selected and makes `Sheet3` the active sheet, whereas `Worksheets("Sheet2").Select` makes `Sheet3` the sole selected and active sheet.

Comment: I think I have to add that there seems to be a difference between:
a) Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
and
b) Sheets(Array("Sheet3", "Sheet2")).Select

=> In a) the "Sheet2" is active afterwards, in b) the "Sheet3" is active afterwards. => Always the first in the list.

Answer (score 17):

`.activate` is  you clicking on the worksheet tab.

`.select` simulates you doing a control and click on the tab. In VBA you're not in the sheet yet.

You can `.select` more than one sheet but `.activate` only one.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the above: When the code below is run with  Replace:=False  no worksheet deactivation event occurs on sheet4.  If Replace:=True is used instead then the de-activation event will fire.

Preventing the event is desirable in most circumstances as it can cause unexpected behaviour.

This means that select is only the equivalent of CTRL+Clicking a worksheet tab IF replace:=false is used.

sub a

```
Dim rng As Range

Sheet4.Select Replace:=False
Set rng = Selection

Sheet5.Select Replace:=True
Selection = rng.Value
```

end sub

Thanks for your posts as it helped me understand the difference.

Harvey