# How do i select worksheet using an inputbox in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select a worksheet every time when i open up a workbook using an inputbox in VBA. here is my code for opening a workbook but after i open up my workbook, how do i select a worksheet inside that workbook?

```
     Sub button7_click()
         dim wb as string
         dim ss as string

           wb = Application.GetOpenFilename
               if wb <> "False" Then Workbooks.Open wb

      End sub
```

Comment: workbooks(wb).worksheets(yourWS)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Sheet1" is the name of the sheet that you want to select...

```
Workbooks(wb).Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

EDIT: And you can use something like this to get a variable sheet name from an InputBox.  In its simplest form...

```
Dim Result As String

Result = InputBox("Provide a sheet name.")
Workbooks(wb).Sheets(Result).Select
```

...but I would add some error handling into this also to prevent errors from blanks, misspelled or invalid sheet names.

Comment: sorry about confusion, i want for the user to prompt a box to choose worksheet, what if they have a different sheet name like aa instead sheet1

Comment: then use inputbox, or even msgbox. Following the microsoft help link (F1) of these should suffice for explanations.

Comment: Updated the answer with InputBox approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a "normal", blank Excel workbook with sheets "Sheet1", "Sheet2" and "Sheet3". Now, when the workbook opens, let's assume you want to *activate* (not select, as [that's different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919455/what-is-the-difference-between-sheets-select-and-sheets-activate)) the sheet called "Sheet2".

In your workbook's `ThisWorkbook` module, add this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

End Sub
```

Make sure this code is pasted inside of the `ThisWorkbook` object and not in a Module, Form, or Sheet object.

Save and exit the workbook. When you re-open it, "Sheet2" will be the active sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code if anyone wants it.
Multiple selections are not quite possible , as the copied worksheet only copies across and increments the largest value of the range selected rather than all the cells selected individually ....

```
Sub CopyAndIncrement()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim myValue As Integer
Dim wsName As String


wsName = InputBox("Provide the EXACT sheet name you want to copy.")
'error handling loop for Worksheet name
For p = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Worksheets(p).Name = wsName Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next p
   
  If Not exists Then
    While exists = False
     wsName = InputBox("Sheet not found re-enter name.")
        For p = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If Worksheets(p).Name = wsName Then
            exists = True
            End If
        Next p
    Wend
  End If

Set Rng = Application.InputBox( _
  Title:="Increment your worksheet", _
  Prompt:="Select a cell(s) you want to increment", _
  Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Test to ensure User Did not cancel

'Set Rng = Rng.Cells(1, 1) 'Set Variable to first cell in user's input (ensuring only 
'1 cell) >> commenting this can give multiple selections
 
 myValue = InputBox("How many time do you want it to increment? Give me the number ")
  
    Do While Count < myValue
      
      For Each ws In Worksheets   ' this loop selects the last sheet in the workbook
          LastWs = ws.Name
          i = ws.Range(Rng.Address).Value
          If i > j Then
              j = i
          End If
      Next
      
    Sheets(wsName).Select
    Sheets(wsName).Copy After:=Sheets(LastWs)
    ActiveSheet.Range(Rng.Address).Value = j + 1
    Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```